# how to declare that a given class implements an interface in Facebook Flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have the following code using Flow:

```
// @flow    
'use strict';

import assert from 'assert';

declare interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    distanceTo(other: IPoint): number;
}

class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    distanceTo(a: IPoint): number {
        return distance(this, a);
    }
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}


function distance(p1: IPoint, p2: IPoint): number {
    function sq(x: number): number {
        return x*x;
    }
    return Math.sqrt( sq(p2.x-p1.x)+sq(p2.y-p1.y) );
}

assert(distance ( new Point(0,0), new Point(3,4))===5);
// distance ( new Point(3,3), 3); // Flow complains, as expected
assert((new Point(0,1)).distanceTo(new Point(3,5))===5);
// (new Point(0,1)).distanceTo(3); // Flow complains as expected
```

Running `npm run flow` yields no complains as expected, whereas the commented-out lines give rise to warnings (again, as expected).

So all's well with the world except that I don't know how  to make it explicit at the point where class `Point` is defined that it is "implementing" interface `IPoint`. Is there a way to do so or is it not idiomatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it:

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        (this: IPoint);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

The key part is `(this: IPoint)`. From JS VM's point of view it's just an expression that does nothing, but Flow needs to check if casting `this` to `IPoint` is valid, effectively checking if class implements `IPoint` interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate, or provide some docs? Just trying to see exactly why this works. Thanks!

Comment: If your linter complains about [`no-unused-expressions`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions), you might need to write `void (this: IPoint);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way to do it is:

```
interface IPoint { ... }
class Point { ... }

(Point: Class<IPoint>); // checks that Point is a class that implements IPoint
```

Comment: Does this same thing apply to things that are not ES6 classes? Say if I had a function like the following: 

`type ISomeAPI = { apiMethod: (..args) => void }`
`const myFunc = (service: Class<ISomeAPI>) => { ... }`

Could service be a normal object (`{ apiMethod: () => {...} }`)or function object (e.g. `function ClassName() {}`)?

Answer (score 0):

As of `0.57.3` (and quite possibly earlier) one can do:

```
class Point implements IPoint {
... // rest of class definition
}
```